# GeoServer / OpenLayers

Tags: geoserver

I´ve installed GeoServer and Java 11 as requested, but when I try to open a layer in the OpenLayers option it send me an error message:

> HTTP ERROR 500 javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment$LocalGE

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: are you really sure you are not using Java 17 (or later)? Might be worth removing the marlin.jar

Comment: From lib folder of Geoserver?

Comment: Yes, please read the manual